# CiviCRM Membership form Renewal text not displaying

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I have a question about the functionality of membership forms for renewals.

We've got our CiviCRM membership form set up with both new membership and renewal text/copy:
[image]

As I understand it, it's the same page that changes title/text based on the member status.

I can't for the life of me get this renewal title/copy to appear on our [membership page](https://vitiligosociety.org/membership). Does anyone know how this title/text change is triggered? 
Does it appear because of a membership status eg 'grace'/'expired'? 
Would it appear with a membership status as 'current' but nearing the end date of the membership?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

It should appear if the user is logged in or is using a checksum and has a Membership status which can be renewed, eg New, Current, Grace

Comment: Thanks Peter/Jitendra. I've tested this with an expired membership and logged in and navigated to our membership page (vitiligosociety.org/membership) and it's still not showing this renewal text.

Is it possible that our JS customisations on the page are causing this?

Answer (score 2):

> I can't for the life of me get this renewal title/copy to appear on our membership page

If a contact has a valid existing membership - the renewal text is shown on the page. This renewal text is not shown if -

- existing membership is in Pending or Cancelled status.
- existing membership is of type = Lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

In our CiviCRM system, the "Renewal" area will show in the form only when the current membership is already expired, while the "Registration"/"New Membership" area will show when the current membership has the status Ongoing.